# Remove newline from string output

Tags: python, database

```py
try:
    with cx_oracle.connect(user,password,dsn,encoding ="UTF-8") as connection:                      
        cursor = connection.cursor()                                                                  
        cursor.execute("select * from customer")                                                       
        results =cursor.fetchall()                                                                      
        return json.dumps(results,indent=4,sort_keys = True,default=str)                                                   
except Exception as error:                                                                            
    print ("error occurred",error)
```

output

```
'[\n [\n 1456,\n   "ice kle",\n  "2022:02:08 8:06:01",\n  "2022-02-08 8:07:01",\n "fund"\n]'
```

Comment: The code returns JSON but your output is not a JSON type. Could you clarifiy the question in more detail?

Comment: that output is a valid json string (at least per pythons json spec).... @SangkeunPark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just dont tell it to format the json

`json.dumps(results)` instead of `json.dumps(results,indent=4...)`

if you really just want to keep that json dumps for some reason and instead remove the newlines ... just do

```
result = result.replace("\n","")
```

Comment: result = result.replace("\n","") after replace with code , received error -  Error occurred 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: no `result = call_the_function_you_have_above_that_returns_json()` ... but just get rid of the indent=4 and the other format params for the json ... theres no need for that junk

Answer (score 0):

Better replace the '\n' with ''
`result = result.replace('\n','')`

Comment: result = result.replace("\n","") after replace with code , received error -  Error occurred 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Answer (score 0):

The indent=4 argument in json.dumps call is responsible for the pretty print(with newlines).
Remove the argument if want all of the result in single line.

@Joran 's answer is correct. I don't have the reputation to add a comment so adding it as answer.